# 2+2=4 becomes 2 2=4 (where did the + go?)

Tags: php, laravel, post

This is very strange to me. I am trying to submit a POST request to my controller that saves to the database. But all the +'s have become empty spaces! I'm guessing it has something to do with encoding but I'm not sure how to preserve the +'s

With Postman I make a new POST request to my route

```
POST https://log.mywebsite.com/
key: log_message
value: 2+2=4
```

Here is the controller that handles the request:

```
$log_message                = new LogMessages;
$log_message->log_message   = $request->log_message;
$log_message->created_at    = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$log_message->save();
```

In the database this is what I end up with:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+
| id | log_message | created_at          |
+----+-------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 2 2=4       | 2019-09-26 12:01:12 |
+----+-------------+---------------------+
```

How can I make sure the + is not lost in the process?

*P.S. When I make the same request with axios, it preserves the +'s*

Comment: In HTTP the character `+` has a special meaning. You need to URL-encode your POST request bodies.

Comment: In particular, `+` should be encoded as `%2B` (See http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should change the Collation  of log_message to utf8mb4